# Can't load image from uri after reload app

Tags: java, android, imageview, sharedpreferences

```
*//Sorry for bad eng, but in stackoverflow.ru I have no answers you my last chance*
```

I have app with 1 activity, which should take image\photo from galery, save `uri` of this image\photo in `sharedPreferences`, and after reload, app load image from saved `uri` in imageView

So, after reload `uri` successfully saved and load in app, but app can't load photo from `uri` and instead image I have empty space, but `ImageView` exist and with loaded `uri` all ok(I compare loaded `uri` and `uri` from galery, they equals).

Below I attach my code and screenshots:

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ua.bellkross.testapp.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/myphoto2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**java:**

```
package ua.bellkross.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView imageView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String photoUri;
    boolean can;

    final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        loadPhoto();
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        savePhoto();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageView :
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        photoUri = selectedImage.toString();
        Log.d("myLog", "savedURI == " + photoUri);
        can = true;
    }

    private void savePhoto(){
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("uri",photoUri);
        editor.putBoolean("edited",can);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void loadPhoto(){
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("edited",false)) {
            String savedURI = sharedPreferences.getString("uri", null);
            if (!savedURI.equals(null)) {
                Log.d("myLog", "savedURI!=null");
                imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(savedURI));
                Log.d("myLog", "savedURI == " + savedURI);
            }
        }
        can = false;
    }
}
```

---

```
//I have no reputation to post images and more than 2 links
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/hveS0.jpg - start app
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrzHF.jpg - take image from galery
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwy37.jpg - after reload app
```

---

That I did for fix it?

1)Check saved and loaded `uri` with `uri` from galery - they equals, I did this with logs

```
05-09 22:05:24.893 524-524/ua.bellkross.testapp D/myLog: savedURI(OnActivityResult) == content://media/external/images/media/16493
05-09 22:05:29.505 1294-1294/? D/myLog: savedURI!=null
05-09 22:05:29.510 1294-1294/? D/myLog: savedURI == content://media/external/images/media/16493
```

2)Try use `getSharedPreferences` instead `sharedPreferences` - it's don't help

3)Try use `imageView.setImageURI(null)`, `imageView.invalidate()`, `imageView.postInvalidate()`, before load of image - don't help.

4)Checked version of my Android and version from `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` - they equals, all ok

5)Try change `uri` from `content://media/external/images/media/16493` to `media/external/images/media/16493` - didn't help

6)Try use `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstanceState` - it's don't help and `onRestoreInstanceState` started only when you change orientation of screen, but not after reload.

Maybe, if u run it yourself or just write similar app(it takes 5-10 min) and this app will work - in compare becomes clear, which mistake I have.

---

**Guys, I find answer, thank for this - greenapps**

I try open stream `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`
and get stack trace and found some string

```
05-10 16:13:40.081 1264-1286/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/18553 from pid=8465, uid=10268 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

So, just write in AndroidManifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Please do a test where you try to open an InputStream for the saved uri. InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); Please report if you can open it. Do it both in onActivityResult and later after restart.

Comment: In onActivityResult all ok
but when I do "InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(photoUri));" in loadPhoto() I get exception

Comment: OH, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
I FIND ANSWER
I should write in Android Manifest 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
I just read my stack trace and find answer, that I have no law for find image in phone "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: Very strange all.For content shemes one does not need permissions as far as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try open stream `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`
and get stack trace and found some string

```
05-10 16:13:40.081 1264-1286/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/18553 from pid=8465, uid=10268 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

So, just write in AndroidManifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Well apparently you develop for Android < 6 as for 6 and above you would als need to ask for permission at runtime. So be prepared ;-).

Comment: ha....now I understand....it seemed like a new question at the beginning...sorry for that... :)..hadn´t seen the edit on the question and just can´t get it in context...

Answer (score 0):

try to set imageView to null at first and then set it normally like this:

```
imageView.setImageURI(null);
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(savedURI));
```